# How to sync different fps video inputs

Tags: x11, video, ffmpeg, camera

I want to do something similar to the one on this [guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites#Withwebcamoverlaypicture-in-picturePiP) but in that case both inputs have the same fps, I want to sync two distinct framerate inputs, here a sample:

```
ffmpeg \
  -f x11grab \
  -video_size 1920x1080 \
  -framerate 60 \
  -i :0.0 \
  -f v4l2 \
  -video_size 320x240 \
  -framerate 15 \
  -i /dev/video0 \
  -filter_complex '[0:v][1:v]overlay=10:(H-h)/2[o]' \
  -map '[o]' \
  -r 60 \
  -vcodec libx264 \
  -an \
  -f mpegts \
  udp://127.0.0.1:3333
```

Then to watch: `vlc udp://@127.0.0.1:3333`

In my case it awkwardly gives about 10 fps and seems to be freezing, though I expected 60 I believe it would be more likely to be 15 since it is the lowest one, who knows...

However if I remove the webcam input and the filter it gives the full 60 fps I wanted, as well as when I stream only the webcam it gives the 15 fps.

Based on [this other guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ChangingFrameRate) I also tried the filter `[1:v]fps=fps=60[wc];[0:v][wc]overlay=10:(H-h)/2[o]` but with no success.

I expect the output fps to be 60 and the frames to be nicely distributed someway avoiding the freezing effect. How can I sync two different fps videos inputs with ffmpeg?

**Evidences**:

- [screen recording with webcam](https://youtu.be/XWfy5B2Qwzc)
- [screen recording without webcam](https://youtu.be/_IO0G_Fzv60) it implies that the computer is capable to record the fullscreen in realtime.
- [logs](https://gist.github.com/tiagoapimenta/b20cf32eaa645b68c9193c66f9255a28) - Stream with and without webcam

Comment: Not clear what you mean by sync. Do you mean output speed?

Comment: Somehow, I expect the output fps to be 60, but I also want the frames to be nicely distributed, if you run the command you see it seems to pick the first 10 frames, then drop the next 50, the result seems a freezing video.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan I attached the logs on the question, also the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know exactly why, but the following worked:

```
ffmpeg \
  -f x11grab \
  -video_size 1920x1080 \
  -framerate 60 \
  -i :0.0 \
  -f v4l2 \
  -video_size 320x240 \
  -framerate 15 \
  -i /dev/video0 \
  -filter_complex '[0:v]setpts=RTCTIME-RTCSTART[dt];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[wc];[dt][wc]overlay=10:(H-h)/2[o]' \
  -map '[o]' \
  -r 60 \
  -vcodec libx264 \
  -an \
  -f mpegts \
  udp://127.0.0.1:3333
```

Although the documentation said `RTCTIME` is deprecated, and most people use `PTS-STARTPTS`, it seems I forced the stream to be time based stead of a number sequence.

**Edit:**

With the following filter also works and I believe it is better suitable:

```
[0:v]setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[dt];[1:v]setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,fps=fps=60[wc];[dt][wc]overlay=10:(H-h)/2[o]
```

It insures the fixed framerate and also adjust the webcam to have the same one as expected on the output.